# Merge tables and remove duplicates: Use Join, Union or both

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with the same structure, similar to those:

A:

```
gid, col
1, 23
2, 24
5, 63
```

B:

```
gid, col
1, 54
3, 223
5, 32
```

I want to have a merged table like this:

```
gid, colA, colB
1, 23, 54
2, 24, null
3, null, 223
5, 63, 32
```

Somehow I dont manage. I tried JOIN and UNION, but the best results are just close:

JOIN:

```
SELECT A.gid, A.col, B.col FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.col=B.col
```

resulting in something like this (just entries from table A):

```
gid, colA, colB
1, 23, 54
2, 24, null
5, 63, 32
```

UNION:

```
select distinct(gid), a, b FROM(
 select A.gid , A.col as a, null as b from A UNION 
 select B.gid, null as a, B.col as b from B
)
as foo
```

achiving only this (duplicate entries):

```
gid, colA, colB
1, 23, null
1, null, 54
2, 24, null
3, null, 223
5, 63, null
5, null, 32
```

Unfortunately, I dont get those two merged to my desired result. i guess its not that difficult but somehow I am running against a wall.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT function.

Comment: Is it mysql or postgresql? Both of them are distinct softwares from different vendors. Please use only those tags which are related to this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentely checked mysql, should have been just sql. So I use postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

In **PostgreSQL**, Oracle and SQL Server you can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT A.gid, A.col, B.col FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.gid = B.gid
```

MySQL does not support full outer join, so you have to use a union with two joins:

```
SELECT A.gid, A.col, B.col FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.gid = B.gid
UNION
SELECT B.gid, A.col, B.col FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON A.gid = B.gid
```

**Note:** This syntax will work on most RDBMS, however it will provide different result than the `FULL OUTER JOIN` if there are duplicates in the joined columns.

**Edit**

This handles duplicates in the joined columns:

```
SELECT A.gid, A.col, B.col FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.gid = B.gid)
UNION ALL
SELECT B.gid, A.col, B.col FROM A RIGHT JOIN B ON A.gid = B.gid
  WHERE A.gid IS NULL
```

**Edit**

The actual solution by the OP (from the comments below)

> Its basically the same as the mysql query from above but doing a `GROUP BY` before on each table to remove duplicates inside each table before. **Note**: In my case, its ok, to sum up the values of duplicates.

```
SELECT
  t1.gid,
  t1.c,
  t2.c
FROM
  (SELECT gid, SUM(A.col) AS c FROM A GROUP BY gid) t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT gid, SUM(B.col) AS c FROM B GROUP BY gid) t2
    ON A.gid = B.gid

UNION

SELECT
  t2.gid,
  t1.c,
  t2.c
FROM
  (SELECT gid, SUM(B.col) AS c FROM B GROUP BY gid ) t2
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT gid, SUM(A.col) AS c FROM A GROUP BY gid) t1
    ON A.gid = B.gid
```

Comment: I get an error on the postgresql query:
ERROR:  FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions. Do I miss something??

Comment: Just to read the documentation or to use google (or your favourite search engine). I am not a pgsql guy, but this message suggests me that the join condition is not that simple in your real case than in the example. You can always fall back to the MySQL syntax, it will work in all database engines.

Comment: I tried the mysql version which works perfectly in postgresql too, as you said. But you are also right, with duplicates in gid column in one table, the result is different and not all entries are found then. Anyway I think that works for me.

Comment: You are welcome! I just added a solution which solves the problem with duplicates in the joined columns.

Comment: Actually, in my case, both queries return the same result. They join duplicates that occur in both tables but duplicates from the same table result in two entries. Can one make them be merged (e.g. summed up), so the result contains a single entry for each gid, having just one value from table a and one from table b?

Comment: What I finally used is this query:
`SELECT t1.gid, t1.c, t2.c FROM (select gid, SUM(A.col) as c FROM A GROUP BY gid) t1 LEFT JOIN (select gid, SUM(B.col) as c FROM B GROUP BY gid) t2 ON A.gid = B.gid
UNION
SELECT t2.gid, t1.c, t2.c FROM (select gid, SUM(B.col) as c FROM B GROUP BY gid) t2 LEFT JOIN (select gid, SUM(A.col) as c FROM A GROUP BY gid) t1 ON A.gid = B.gid`
Its basically the same as the mysql query from above but doing a `GROUP BY` before on each table to remove duplicates inside each table before. Note: In my case, its ok, to sum up the values of duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. I've added it to the answer for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

set query with **full outer join** like all A table with all B table and set null where not return value

```
select a.gid, A.Col as colAn b.col as ColB 
    From A full outer join b on A.gid=b.gid
```